# Recursive calculation in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I'm having a tough time finding a solution to ETL some data into my resulting table. I think I cannot accomplish this using pure SQL and need to use PL-SQL due to the looping. Could the sql gurus help me go towards the right direction or provide some pointers to solve this problem?

Here's the scenario:
Tables: TABLEA and TABLEB.

Steps:

1. Group records in TABLEA by A_CD and SUM the A_AMT FIELD. (Lets assume A_FLAG is always same for any A_CD.). Lets call the grouped resultset as TABLEA_GRP (This is not a table, it is a grouped query).
2. Pick a row from TABLEB and if B_FLG is 'N' then pick all rows in TABLEA_GRP where A_FLG is 'N'. If the B_FLG is 'Y' then pick all rows in TABLEA_GRP.
3. Starting first record of rows picked in step 2, calculate the ratio of its TOTAL_AMT to SUM of ALL TOTAL_AMT for the selected rows. Multiply the ratio to B_AMT and add resulting amount to the rows TOTAL_AMT and store in RESULTING_AMT. Repeat this calculation for all rows picked in step 2.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3, now using the starting TOTAL_AMT VALUE from the RESULTING_AMT value from previous calculation of the same A_CD.

RESULTING _RATIO field is not needed to be saved, it is just given for demo purpose. How would you do this?

Basically I want to get data in RESULTING_TABLE from TABLEA and TABLEB

Could anyone help? Thanks a lot in advance for any guidance.

[image: Table Design with sample data]

EDIT: I added A_DATE and B_DATE for supporting join between the two tables. For simplicity you can just do A.A_DATE = B.B_DATE, example this basic join:

```
SELECT
  A.A_CD,
  SUM(A.A_AMT) AS TOTAL_AMT,
  A.A_FLAG,
  A.A_DATE,
  B.B_ID,
  B.B_AMT,
  B.B_FLAG
FROM
  TABLEA A
JOIN TABLEB B
ON A.A_DATE = B.B_DATE
GROUP BY
  A.A_CD,
  A.A_FLAG,
  A.A_DATE,
  B.B_ID,
  B.B_AMT,
  B.B_FLAG
;
```

[image: Resulting data of above join]

Comment: Just to clarify: did I understand step 2 correctly? My result for step 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7670/2/0

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Ok, which rows you call "first" and "selected" in step 3?

Comment: Selected : Result of this - if B_FLG is 'N' then pick all rows in TABLEA_GRP where A_FLG is 'N'. If the B_FLG is 'Y' then pick all rows in TABLEA_GRP.
First: First row of 'Selected'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I've got the solution. The numbers are a bit different to yours, but I'm fairly sure mine is doing what you want. We can do everything in steps 1 & 2 using a single query (main_sql). 3 and 4 have to be done using a recursive statement (recur_sql).

```
with main_sql as (
    select  a.*,
            b.*,
            sum(a_amt) over (partition by b_id) as cd_amt,
            rank() over (partition by a_cd order by b_id) as rnk
    from   (select a_cd, a_flag, sum(a_amt) as a_amt
            from   tablea
            group  by a_cd, a_flag) a,
            tableb b
    where   a.a_flag = case when b.b_flag = 'Y' then a.a_flag else b.b_flag end
    order by b_id, a_cd
), 
recur_sql (a_cd, b_id, total_amt, cd_amt, resulting_ratio, resulting_amt, rnk) as (
    select m.a_cd, 
           m.b_id, 
           m.a_amt as total_amt, 
           m.cd_amt, m.a_amt / m.cd_amt as resulting_ratio, 
           m.a_amt + (m.a_amt / m.cd_amt * m.b_amt) as resulting_amt, 
           rnk
    from   main_sql m
    where  rnk = 1

    union all

    select m.a_cd, 
           m.b_id, 
           r.resulting_amt as total_amt, 
           m.cd_amt, 
           r.resulting_amt / m.cd_amt as resulting_ratio, 
           r.resulting_amt + (r.resulting_amt / m.cd_amt * m.b_amt) as resulting_amt,
           m.rnk
    from recur_sql r,
         main_sql m
    where m.rnk > 1
    and   r.a_cd = m.a_cd
    and   m.rnk - 1 = r.rnk

)
select a_cd, b_id, total_amt, resulting_ratio, resulting_amt
from   recur_sql
order by 2, 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I needed. Appreciate the time you took to arrive to this.

Comment: One question though - will this solution be efficient over doing it in stored procedure with cursors when there are few million rows in TABLEA? I cannot test that since I do not have the raw data yet.

Comment: One typo in the calculation : The RESULTING_RATIO is based on the TOTAL_AMT sum in denominator. So any group of B_ID's would have total as 1 for RESULTING_RATIO. In the current solution it is only considering the ratio from the total in main_sql.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you else you would calculate the resulting_ratio value. Are you able to post the PL/SQL code you are working with?
In terms of performance, it's hard to say. It really depends on how the SQL engine handles this kind of recursion. My code above is essentially dynamic programming using only SQL. As with many DP alogorithms the recursive solution can be improved on with a procedural solution by caching each result and using to calculate the next iteration. 
I would suggest creating a synthetic data set and seeing which approach is faster.